# I am trying to write a while loop similar to my for loop.How should I go about it in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop

```
for (i in 1:12) {
  if (i %% 2 ==1) print(i)
}
```

I have written the above code to get the below output:
1
3
5
7
9
11

However, I want the same output using a while loop. How can I do this?

I tried the below but it did not work

```
while (i == 1:12){
  if (i %% 2 ==1) print(i)
}
```

Comment: `i = 1;
while (i <= 12){
  if (i %% 2 ==1) print(i);
  i = i + 1;
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Loops are fine for instances like those described, but not so good for larger problems. If you use `apply`/`lapply`/`sapply` then you can also take advantage of the `parallel` package.

```
unlist(lapply(1:12, function(x) if (x %% 2 == 1) x))
```

alternatively:

```
c(1:12)[1:12 %% 2 == 1]
```

will also give you your answer

Answer (score 0):

If `i` is a vector then try this:

```
i=c(1:12)
i[i%%2==1]
```

Output:

```
[1]  1  3  5  7  9 11
```

**Updated**

```
for(i in 1:12){
  if(i%%2==1){
    print(i)
     if(i==3){
      print("three")
    }  
  }
 }
```

Output:

```
[1] 1
[1] 3
[1] "three"
[1] 5
[1] 7
[1] 9
[1] 11
```

Comment: this worked, I am also trying to print the word three when 3 appears in output,but its giving me an error                                                                                               
    for (i in 1:12) {
  if (i %% 2 ==1) print(i)
  ifelse (i=3,"three",i)}

Comment: @user10001876: I have updated answer as per your suggestion!